# What kind of rice is used for Jamaican rice and peas?

Tags: rice

I'm about to make Jamaican rice and peas, and I'm not quite sure if I want a long, medium, or short grain rice. What is traditional in the islands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm by no means an official source, but it looks like a long grain rice is used. [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_and_peas) shows an example made with [Basmati rice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmati_rice), and links to [this recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/emeril-lagasse/jamaican-rice-and-peas-recipe/index.html), which calls for long grain rice.

Comment: I think this is probably correct; the more I think about it, there is a lot of (East) Indian influence in the islands (roti!) so I wouldn't be surprised if basmati varieties were popular there.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use regular long grain rice. I don't think basmati would be appropriate, however, since it doesn't grow in the caribbean and so would probably be out of the price range of a gastronomic staple like peas 'n' rice.